# Пропал весь код и превратился в null как можно исправить?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, null

Здраствуйте, редактировал файлы в vscode потом после перезагрузки в файлах все данные пропали когда я открывал в webstorm весь код превратился в null, а в блокноте вообще пустота одни пробелы но файл весит 5kb как вернуть коды.

Comment: Программисты делятся на тех кто ещё не использует систему контроля версий и тех кто уже использует

Comment: Ну, как говорится, Press F to pay respects)

Comment: В VSCode же есть timeline вроде, не знаю правда, работает ли оно на отдельно открытые файлы. Там можно откатиться.